# Is it possible to start a timer in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

For instance, check a status every 30 seconds or poll a web service periodically ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

App Engine [Cron Service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) allows you to configure regularly scheduled tasks that operate at defined times or regular intervals

A `cron.yaml` file in the root directory of your application (alongside `app.yaml`) configures scheduled tasks for your Python application.
For example:

```
- description: Webservice polling
  url: /tasks/pollawebservice
  schedule: every 30 minutes
```

The `url` field specifies a URL in your application that will be invoked by the Cron Service.

Comment: As far as I can tell you can't use the app engine cron service for jobs at frequencies of less than 1 minute. Do you have a solution for something like an API call every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the [task queue](http://code.google.com/intl/da-DK/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html). A task can be [configured](http://code.google.com/intl/da-DK/appengine/docs/python/config/queue.html) to run at custom intervals and can perform pretty much any action.

Comment: I would use Gae Cron service for this purpose.