# Why do I get java.security.AccessControlException as I initialize the Timer instance?

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, timer

Following exception gets thrown:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" 
"modifyThreadGroup")
```

as I try to run my application deployed on Google App Engine.

The stacktrace tells the cause of the exception to be the following statement, that forms a part of the deployed code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(); // CAUSE OF EXCEPTION
timer.schedule(new PTimerTask(), 10, 60000);
```

I have known that GAE has some differences with *Java Thread Mechanism*. But that is all I know.
I am unaware of the cause of this exception.

What is it and how can I get rid of the exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the appengine [cron service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) to run periodic tasks.

See a similar previous post about Python: [Is it possible to start a timer in google app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828214/is-it-possible-to-start-a-timer-in-google-app-engine)

EDIT: Added link to appengine Java cron service

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of Java classes supported by App Engine:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist

java.util.Timer is on the list.

You can read the following explanation of the use of Threads in App Engine:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#The_Sandbox

Comment: A Java application can create a new thread, but there are some restrictions on how to do it. These threads can't "outlive" the request that creates them.

This pretty much negates the purpose of a long interval timer OP is attempting to create.